# $http GET method Displays Blank Page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I tried to parse json using below code but it is displaying a blank page.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http:krispypapad.herokuapp.com/fetch_article").success(function (response) {   
      $scope.myWelcome = data.response;

    });  
});
```

Comment: See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/5535245).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is typo with the URL you are using:

`http:krispypapad.herokuapp.com` instead `http://krispypapad.herokuapp.com` you are missing a couple of `//`

This is how your code will look like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://krispypapad.herokuapp.com/fetch_article").success(function (response) {   
      $scope.myWelcome = response; //<-- no .data is required

    });  
});
```

Comment: The `.success` method does not return a response object. Use the `.then` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the URL, it should be like this:

```
http://krispypapad.herokuapp.com/whatever
```

Also you should use `response.data` not `data.response`

Comment: The `.success` method does not return a response object. Use the `.then` method instead.